# "Known good" review audits not updated, and still show 5 fake close-voters instead of 3 fake close voters

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits

In the reopen queue, we can tell that a review is an audit, because 5 users are shown to have closed a question at a time when 3 close votes would have been sufficient to close the question:

#### Example 1

[image]

#### Example 2

[image]

Both questions were "fake closed" and I should click on *Reopen*, but I should come to this conclusion because of their contents, not because I can tell it from the number of close voters.

Comment: I can agree with that, but I think it would be a simple change to create 3 fake close voters instead of 5.

Comment: Meh, I don't think this is a valid dupe. The audits should show be updated so they show 3 close voters, not 5 as it used to be.

Comment: Ideally, the number of real close votes it takes to close a question and the number of close voters shown in an audit should be the same variable, internally. Other than that, I don’t see why time should be invested in fixing this.

Comment: It's a bit weird, but you *noticed* that fact, which means presumably you're paying attention to reviews? Which also means it might be a beneficial bug in a way :p.

Comment: Indeed, I payed attention *while I was still surprised* by the unusual number of close voters. But now that I know it, I might just click "Reopen" without looking at the question. Unless it's a trick!

Comment: Honestly, you need _very_ little attention to see it's closed by 5 voters. Things like the wrong tag do indicate you at least scrolled far enough to have read the body and have read the tags, but spotting 5 close votes is one of the first things you'll read. This should be fixed.

Comment: I don't agree. Audits are only there to make sure you pay attention, they are not there to test your reviewing skills. I'm all for there being little tells that you're seeing an audit, it offsets the fact that there are quite some terrible audit questions.

Comment: Can't be 100% certain but I *think* I have had such an audit with only 3 fake close voters. Maybe I was dreaming?

Comment: “I should come to this conclusion because of their contents, not because I can tell it from the number of close voters.” - It takes less than 10 seconds to open the question in another tab.  Audits are designed so you will pass provided you are paying attention.  More users really should review the actual question before selecting  a choice while performing a review

Answer (score 5):

With the redesign of the review page, we no longer show the close voters in a post notice for the question being reviewed. Thus this is *de facto* fixed. (That said, I have also fixed the logic behind the scenes where we retrieve this data, so in case we change the UI in the future to display the close voters again, this will be fixed).